# Java acquire monitor lock of other class

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

Let's say I have this class:

```
public class Status {
   private int x;

   // monitor lock?
   public Object myLock = new Object();

   public Status(int x) {
      this.x = x;
   }

   public int checkVar() {
      return x;
   }

   public int incrementVar() {
      ++x;
   }
}
```

Then I have a thread class like this:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

   public void run() {
        // Is this how to acquire monitor lock of Status class?
        synchronized (statusInstance.myLock) {
          statusInstance.checkVar();
          statusInstance.incrementVar();
        }
   }    
}
```

This is how you acquire the monitor lock of another class right?

Comment: you can as well use synchronized (statusInstance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Java` if you have a reference to any object you can use it as a `mutex`. But you would be locking on the object and not the class.

The problem is that anyone can mutate that object because it is public and obtain a lock they shouldn't be acquiring.

```
 statusInstance.myLock = new Object();
```

Using public mutable objects as mutexes is considered harmful. You can lock on the class given there is only one class in the `ClassLoader`

```
 synchronized(Status.class){
    ..
 }
```

Or making your lock static final

```
public static final Object MY_LOCK = new Object();
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct. You can also use the object itself as the lock by using:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

   public void run() {
     // Is this how to acquire monitor lock of Status class?
     synchronized (statusInstance) {
       statusInstance.checkVar();
       statusInstance.incrementVar();
     }
   }    
}
```

which is simpler because you don't need to declare `myLock` anymore.